# SQL Join Incorrectly

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join

I'm attempting to select values from the databases pictured below so that I may insert into a new table called `Desired Table`.  Data and debugging is in a `Microsoft Access` database and I continue to receive the error:

> syntax error in query expression.

What is wrong with this query? The joins seem correct and so does the `FROM` clause.  Please let me know if you need more information.  Don't worry about the `INSERT` clause.

Query:

```
SELECT vicdescriptions.vid, 
       vicdescriptions.make, 
       vicdescriptions.vic_year, 
       vicdescriptions.optiontable, 
       vacdescriptions.accessory, 
       vacvalues.value, 
       vicvalues.valuetype, 
       vicvalues.value 
FROM   vicdescriptions 
       JOIN vicvalues 
         ON ( vicdescriptions.vic_make = vicvalues.vic_make 
              AND vicdescriptions.vic_year = vicvalues.vic_year );
```

Database Structure:

[DATABASE SCHEMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcqF5.jpg)

Desired table for insertion:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT VicDescriptions.VID, 
       VicDescriptions.Make, 
       VicDescriptions.VIC_Year, 
       VicDescriptions.OptionTable, 
       VacDescriptions.accessory, 
       VacValues.value, 
       VacValues.valuetype, 
       VacValues.value --(No such table as VicValues available in the database, you only have VacValues)
FROM   VicDescriptions 
       JOIN VacValues --(No such table available in the database, you only have VacValues) 
         ON ( VicDescriptions.VIC_Make = VacValues.VIC_Make 
              AND VicDescriptions.VIC_Year = VacValues.VIC_Year )
       JOIN VacDescriptions
         ON ( VacDescriptions.Period = VacValues.Period
               AND VacDescriptions.VAC = VacValues.VAC);
```

Comment: I think you are using tables and columns which do not exist in your database the "VicDescriptions" table doesn't seem to have the accessory column and there is no table as "VicValues" in your database (according to the schema you have provided)

Comment: I will have to test this.

Comment: Updated the schema.  Yours works so far minus the accessory.

Comment: I have added the accessory column. Hope this helps!

Comment: So far so good but I am getting an error saying "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.  Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 4):

Access does not support `JOIN` as a synonym for `INNER JOIN`.  You must always specify the type of `JOIN`:

```sql
FROM   vicdescriptions 
       INNER JOIN vicvalues 
         ON ( vicdescriptions.vic_make = vicvalues.vic_make 
              AND vicdescriptions.vic_year = vicvalues.vic_year )
```

If there is not a table named `vicvalues`, Access will give you a different error message after you have changed `JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use *parenthesis* only when you join more than *two*
 tables in `Ms-Access` plus it should start before first table name.  Try removing it.

```
.....
FROM   vicdescriptions 
       JOIN vicvalues 
         ON vicdescriptions.vic_make = vicvalues.vic_make 
             AND vicdescriptions.vic_year = vicvalues.vic_year
```

Comment: Is this the complete query

Comment: Yes it is the complete query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT vicdescriptions.vid, 
       vicdescriptions.make, 
       vicdescriptions.vic_year, 
       vicdescriptions.optiontable, 
       vacdescriptions.accessory, 
       vacvalues.value, 
       vicvalues.valuetype, 
       vicvalues.value 
FROM   vicdescriptions 
       JOIN vicvalues 
         ON ( vicdescriptions.vic_make = vicvalues.vic_make 
              AND vicdescriptions.vic_year = vicvalues.vic_year );
```

I guess line 5, 6 vacdescriptions, vacvalues >> vicdescriptions, vicvalues

Comment: Says there's an error in the "FROM" clause.  Access is NOT intuitive to debug with.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a typo for vacdescriptions and vacvalues?

```
SELECT vicdescriptions.vid, 
       vicdescriptions.make, 
       vicdescriptions.vic_year, 
       vicdescriptions.optiontable, 
       **vicdescriptions.accessory, 
       vicvalues.value,** 
       vicvalues.valuetype, 
       vicvalues.value 
FROM   vicdescriptions 
       JOIN vicvalues 
         ON ( vicdescriptions.vic_make = vicvalues.vic_make 
              AND vicdescriptions.vic_year = vicvalues.vic_year );
```